# Problems with the integration of recaptcha v3 and contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, recaptcha-v3

i have a wordpress page that has a contact form 7, i already created the new recaptcha v3 keys and put them in the integration box, i eliminated the tag [recaptcha] from the form, but i can't make the badge show in any of the pages.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: could you link us to the guide you are following that told you to 'create the new recaptcha v3 keys' ? Any code you can show as well would help.

Comment: https://contactform7.com/recaptcha/ there, i had the form working before with the v2 but i had to upgrade it to v3 and now it's not working